# Async data of Modal using class binding

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

In the vue js task, I tried to implement the label color on html modals. The color on the label is obtained by doing `class binding` based on data from the api. The value of the api, will always change every 3000 ms. So far, the data from the api itself has been stored in a variable and the value of variable has changed based on the api, but the color of the label has not changed. The color of button in table too based on data from api. It has successfully change following the value of `color from data`, but the modal is failed. This is my code:

```
<template>
<div v-if="showModal">
 <transition name="modal">
  <div class="close">
    <span @click="showModal=false"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div v-for="check in device" class="row">                                        
    <label class="statusDevice" v-bind:class="check.color"></label>
    <h4 class="nameDevice col col-5">{{check.name}}</h4>                                                                            
    <label><h4>IP Address :</h4></label>
    <h4>{{check.ipAddress}}</h4>                                        
  </div>
 </transition>
</div>
<card>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td v-for="text in data"><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-text" v-bind:class="text.color" @click="showDetail(text)">{{text.name}}</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: "SampleApp",      
data(){
       return {
         showModal:false,
         device:[],
         data:[]
       }
    },
    methods:{
       showDetail(data){
        this.showModal=true;                                    
        this.device=data.device;                
       },
       getValue(){
         apiService.getListDevice().then((result) => {
            this.data = result.data;
        });      
       }
    },
    created(){
        this.getValue();
        setInterval(()=>this.getValue(),3000);
    }
 }
</script>
```

Anybody can help ??? I have tried using `v-bind:class.sync="check.color"`, but it failed. Thanks before.

Comment: Would you like to show the `check` object or its sample value?

Comment: in JSON, it looks like this @JefryDewangga:
{
   data:
        {
          "context":"test",
          "id":30,
          "ipAddress":"5.32.5.6",
          "name":"device 1",
          "color":"bg-success"
        }
},
the value of color can change to "bg-secondary" or "bg-warning".

Comment: sorry, "color":"btn-success" is the right value

Comment: Is there any error on the console?

Comment: there no error appears in console. Recently, I found out that the parameter `data` in `showDetail` method has not updated based on the change on api. When modal displayed, the `data` in `showDetail` method has not updated. I add new setInterval method, but it failed to access the `index of that data` in `this.data` local variable.

Comment: Is there any reproduction project that can be seen, perhaps in codesandbox? It's hard to help without knowing the context of the project or the source code

Comment: thank @JefryDewangga, it solved. I need to add another setInterval method and then replace this.device with a new data that get from this.data